# How to embed facebook shop page on a website

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, plugins, embed

Is it possible to embed facebook shop page on a website? If it is, how to do it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can embed an entire page using an iframe with the src attribute.

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/path/file"></iframe>
```

You can specify other attributes such as size if you wish.

Comment: That doesn't work for Facebook pages, they use X-Frame-Options / CSP to prevent that.